# (1)f has an antiderivative <-> (2)For every closed path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ we have $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open, non-empty and path-connected, i.e. that every two points can be connected by a path that is continuously differentiable in pieces. Furthermore let ¨
f:$\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continuous. Show that the following statements are then equivalent:

(1)f has an antiderivative

(2)For every closed path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ we have $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$

I had only an idea for (1)->(2)
:

f has an antiderivative means there is a F: $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, F'(z)=f(z) and $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$. because $\gamma\  is\ closed, a=b \
and\ it follows  \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=F(\gamma(a))-F(\gamma(a))$=0

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative_(complex_analysis)#Sufficiency) wiki page

Comment: so my proof for (1)->(2) was correct?

Comment: Mostly, yes, although it might be better if you make it more explicitly clear that you took a parameterization of $\gamma$ to evaluate the line integral. Alternatively, scroll up in the link I posted. :)

Comment: thanks for the link but isnt the proof there only the direction (2)->(1)?

Comment: you mean the text under Sufficiency, right? sorry my english isnt the best. i cant see well that this is a proof for both directions?